# android sdk vertically left align text in vertical linearlayouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a remoteview that contains 3 lines of text/images, each row consisting of 2 textviews and one imageview.

My structure is:-

Vertical Linearlayout
  Horizontal linearlayout
  Horizontal linearlayout
  Horizontal linearlayout.

The layout xml I'm using is:-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/wevents"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/sub3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="+10"
            android:id="@+id/wdays3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Some Text"
            android:id="@+id/wsubject3"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/walarm3"
            android:src="@drawable/bell_white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    ... (each of the other linearlayouts is exactly the same)
```

I have two problems:-

1. I cannot get the second text field to vertically align under its predecessor.
2. If the second text field is too long it pushes the image onto a second line.

So:

1. How do I make it so that all texts left align under each other.
2. How do I limit long text to be truncated with ellipses so that the images also align?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to both 1 and 2 should actually be the same here; you need to change the **layout_width** attribute to 0dp on your TextViews and ImageViews.
So the first TextView should show:

```
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="+10"
        android:id="@+id/wdays3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

And then do the same for the other TextViews and ImageViews.

The problem is that when you use **layout_weight** for these Views in a horizontal LinearLayout, you are saying that the width of each view should be calculated by referring to the weights you've specified, but when you say **layout_width="wrap_content"**, you are saying the widths should be calculated based on what is inside the view, ie the length of text or size of the image. Specifying both methods to calculate the widths will cause some odd results, but if you set the widths to 0dp, then it will just go straight to the weights you have set.

It probably goes without saying, but I'll say it anyway, if you were using weights for items within a vertical linear layout, you would need to set the **layout_height** attributes to 0dp instead.

Comment: Perfect, works like a dream.  Also, many thanks for WHY it works like a dream.  That is the first time that I've seen the layout-weight, layout-width explained so concisely.  Many thanks.